# What are the bounds for this median?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, median

Ok, I can't figure out how to exactly calculate the median.  I have a pdf for a continuous random variable f(x) = x/2, for 0 < x < 2, and 0 otherwise.  I THINK the median is found using something like $$1/2 = \int_0^m x/2 \,dx$$, but I don't know what the lower bound is supposed to be in this context.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.  I had it right.  According to a website
Let X be a continuous random variable. The median of X is the number M such that
P(X ≤ M) = 1/2.

Comment: @johny The median is not the mean.

Answer (score 0):

An answer just for completeness:

In general for a continuous random variable the median is the value $n$ which satisfies $$ \int_{-\infty}^m f(x) \,dx = \frac12$$ which, with the particular density you mention corresponding to a [triangular distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution) with parameters $a=0, b=2, c=2$, indeed gives the expression in your question, leading you to solve $\frac{m^2}{4}=\frac12$, i.e. $m= \sqrt{2}$, slightly more than the mean of $\frac43$ and rather less than the mode of $2$.